# Absolute value of the difference is sufficiently small implies the quotient is close to 1

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

Let $|\cdot|$ be an absolute value on a field $K.$

Let $\alpha \in K^\times$ and $\varepsilon>0$ be given.

I am stuck trying to prove the following statement:

"There exists $\eta>0$ such that for all $\beta \in K^\times$ with $|\alpha-\beta|<\eta\,$ one has $|\alpha\beta^{-1}-1|<\varepsilon$"

---

So for any $\eta>0$ one has 
$$|\alpha-\beta|<\eta \; \Rightarrow \; |\alpha\beta^{-1}-1|<\eta|\beta|^{-1}$$
and so I want to choose my $\eta$ so that
$$\eta<\varepsilon|\beta| \; \text{ for all } \; \beta \in K^\times \; \text{ such that } \; |\alpha-\beta|<\eta.$$
But now I'm stuck because I want a lower bound $|\beta|$ but the inequality is "the wrong way around".

Help greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT (following hint below):** Choose $\eta>0$ such that
$$\eta<\min(1,\varepsilon)\cdot\frac{|\alpha|}{2}.$$
Then, since $\eta<|\alpha|/2,$ one has
$$|\beta|\geq |\alpha|-|\alpha-\beta|>|\alpha|-\frac{|\alpha|}{2}=\frac{|\alpha|}{2}$$
and so, since $\eta<\varepsilon|\alpha|/2,$ it follows that
$$\varepsilon|\beta|>\eta.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show there is an $\eta'$ such that for $|\alpha-\beta|<\eta'$, we have $|\beta|>|\alpha|/2$. Then choose $\eta < \min(\eta', \frac{1}{2}\epsilon |\alpha|)$.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I don't know why but I had a real block with this! I've edited my original post to give the solution following your hint.